# SOLVED QT Bluetooth communication via RFCOMM to Raspberry PI 3

Tags: qt, bluetooth, rfcomm

i am trying to communicate with my mobile app to my raspberry pi 3 and I am using QT to build an app.

I used for the first steps the example project "Bluetooth Chat Example", which is using a RFCOMM-server to communicate with  my Raspberry.

The Raspberry has a bluetooth function and I started the RFCOMM server.

Unfortunately my phone is not recognizing my Raspberry Pi.

Other apps like: Serial Bluetooth terminal are working fine and the communiction is working.

QT-Version: Qt 5.15.0

Does anyone know how to fix this ? I mean why is my app not seeing my raspberry
or the other way around.

If you need further information, just let me know
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/di7e20tnghn8zpk/AACrS6eTc6McejqjGFbX7WX4a?dl=0

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you have some sample code?  Do you have an error message?

Comment: project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/di7e20tnghn8zpk/AACrS6eTc6McejqjGFbX7WX4a?dl=0

Comment: i do not have any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

Changed UUID into following:

UUID changed to:
old code

```
static const QLatin1String serviceUuid("e8e10f95-1a70-4b27-9ccf-02010264e9c8");
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
static const QLatin1String reverseUuid("c8e96402-0102-cf9c-274b-701a950fe1e8");
#endif
```

new code:

```
static const QLatin1String serviceUuid("FB349B5F8000-0080-0001-0000-01110000");
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
static const QLatin1String reverseUuid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
#endif`
```